# how can i stop the typing effect after it completed typing in css

Tags: html, css

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/typewriter-effect/
this snippet of code from this website. I wanted to know is there a way to stop the typing animation after it finished typing the word.

```
<div class="col-twelve">
   <h5>print("Hello, World!")</h5>
</div>

.col-twelve h5 {
  overflow: hidden; /* Ensures the content is not revealed until the animation */
  border-right: 0.15em solid orange; /* The typwriter cursor */
  white-space: nowrap; /* Keeps the content on a single line */
  margin: 0 auto; /* Gives that scrolling effect as the typing happens */
  letter-spacing: 0.15em; /* Adjust as needed */
  animation: typing 3.5s steps(50, end) forwards,
    blink-caret 0.75s step-end infinite;
}

@keyframes typing {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 35%;
  }
}

@keyframes blink-caret {
  from,
  to {
    border-color: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  }
}
```

Comment: I can say you should use JavaScript for doing that. Can you provide any code sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, problem you have encountered is related to the alignment of text.
By default text is aligned to left, add `text-align: center;` to your code, then your text will be centered and effect of the animation not finishing will be gone.